# Moving data contained in one column to many columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which with 2 of these columns look like these:

First one

```
FORMAT # The header
GT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX
GT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX
...
# (exactly the same in all rows)
```

Second one

```
FORMAT2
0/1:48:1582,36:0.0222:20:-0.0009:48
0/1:100:410,103:0.2008:20:-100.0000:100
...
```

I need the info of the first one as a header and the info of the second columns in different columns separate by ":". It should looks like this

```
GT GQ AD VF NL SB GQX
0/1 48 1582,36 0.0222 20 -0.0009 48
0/1 100 410,103 0.2008 20 -100.0000 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df2 = df.FORMAT2.str.split(':', expand=True)
df2.columns = df.FORMAT.iloc[0].split(':')
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
    GT   GQ       AD      VF  NL         SB  GQX
0  0/1   48  1582,36  0.0222  20    -0.0009   48
1  0/1  100  410,103  0.2008  20  -100.0000  100
```

#### Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'FORMAT': {0: 'GT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX', 1: 'GT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX'},
        'FORMAT2': {
            0: '0/1:48:1582,36:0.0222:20:-0.0009:48',
            1: '0/1:100:410,103:0.2008:20:-100.0000:100',
        },
    }
)

df2 = df.FORMAT2.str.split(':', expand=True)
df2.columns = df.FORMAT.iloc[0].split(':')

print(df2)
```